# Resolving multiple keyed services

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I have multiple groups of services that derive from a single interface.  Each group needs to be resolved separately:

```
builder.RegisterType<Bar1>().Keyed<IFoo>("Bars");
builder.RegisterType<Bar2>().Keyed<IFoo>("Bars");
builder.RegisterType<Foo1>().Keyed<IFoo>("Foos");
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>().Keyed<IFoo>("Foos");
```

What does work:

```
var keyfoos = scope.ResolveKeyed<IEnumerable<IFoo>>("Foos");
Console.Write("resolved keyfoos: ");
Console.WriteLine(foos == null ? "null" : keyfoos.Count().ToString());
```

> resolved keyfoos: 2

The actual problem is injecting those keyed services:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public FooBar(
        [KeyFilter("Foos")]
        IEnumerable<IFoo> foos, 
        [KeyFilter("Bars")]
        IEnumerable<IFoo> bars)
    {
        Console.Write("ctor key foos: ");
        Console.WriteLine(foos == null ? "null" : foos.Count().ToString());
        Console.Write("ctor key bars: ");
        Console.WriteLine(bars == null ? "null" : foos.Count().ToString());
    }
}

scope.Resolve<FooBar>();
```

result:

> ctor key foos: 0
>
> ctor key bars: 0

I'd expect both "lists" to have a count of 2 not 0.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering the class with the constructor using the `KeyFilterAttribute` also requires the `WithAttributeFiltering()`

Instead of:

```
builder.RegisterType<FooBar>().AsSelf();
```

I needed to

```
builder.RegisterType<FooBar>().AsSelf().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

So now the result is:

> ctor key foos: 2
>
> ctor key bars: 2